# Establishing connection to server through Windows Mobile 6.0 app

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-mobile-6.5

I recently purchased a Honeywell Dolphin 7800 mobile scanner/computer.  It is running Windows Mobile Embedded Handheld 6.5.  I am writing an app for it to take inventory.  I can debug to the device just fine.  The app has to retrieve and update data from our server (10.0.2.6\MSSQLSERVER2008).  In my solution, I added a dataset and dragged the table I wanted to use over to the dataset designer.  In my code, I fill a datatable using the following:

```
BQData.BQItemsDataTable dt1 = new BQData.BQItemsDataTable();
BQDataTableAdapters.BQItemsTableAdapter ta = new BQ_Inventory.BQDataTableAdapters.BQItemsTableAdapter();
ta.Fill(dt1);
```

I get an "SQL Exception" error when it tries to execute "ta.fill(dt1);" and reverts back to this line in the BQData.Designer.cs file:

```
int returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

I'm thinking the error is in the connection string.  I've tried at least 20 different combinations of connection strings.  To start, I'll provide the one I THINK should work:

```
"Data Source=10.0.2.6\MSSQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=BQData;User ID=sa;Password=timeclock"
```

PLEASE HELP!!

*EDIT*  Don't critique that exact connection string, as I've tried many many different ones.  Two "\"s does not apply in this case as I'm entering this string into the TableAdapter's properties and not as a string in code.  I've tried "persist security info=true", "trusted_connection=true", "datasource=ip,port"... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem of connectionstring for mobile device.

I got it to work with:

Data Source=[ServerIP],1433;Initial Catalog = [DatabaseName]; User ID = [ID]; Password = [Password];

First try it from a remote machine from the database to ensure that the database is setup correctly. If it works it will work on the device